# Which statement would compile fast? !(condition1 && condition2) or !condition1 && !condition2

Tags: java

I know that this is negligible amount of time difference but I got some curiosity as I had more than 5 conditions checking on if loop for my project. I know that for the second one as condition1 becomes false the jvm skips the loop but posting it here if I am wrong or right and any other thoughts.

Example:

```
!("".equals(ASD) && "".equals(XYZ))
```

OR

```
!"".equals(ASD) && !"".equals(XYZ)
```

Comment: Both of the lines have logically different meaning. [`!(A.B) = (!A+!B) != (!A.!B)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: perfect I am so dumb. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"I know that this is negligible amount of time difference but I got some curiosity ..."* - To satisfy your curiosity, it would be more appropriate (IMO) for you to 1) read about how to write a valid Java micro-benchmark, and 2) write your own benchmark.  ('Cos ... basically, that is what you are asking us to do for you ...)

Comment: It's not the compile time you need to worry about, more the execution time :)

Comment: @Conffusion - I disagree.  The most important thing is the developer time wasted on premature optimization!

Comment: [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: @Stephen. My comment was not in response to you but based on the title of this question. When we do performance optimizations it is to optimize execution time, not compile time. That's all I wanted to say. And my experience is also that you solve performance problems when they occure. Of course it's not wrong to keep performance in mind when developing but not to the level of detail as requested in this question.

Answer (score 3):

These both have different meanings.
lets take *condition1*->true and *condition2*->false

```
!(true && false)
!(false)
```

=>True

**But in other case**

```
!true && !False 
False && True
```

=>False

Answer (score 2):

Omkar Arora is making a good point. The conditions are not the same, but if you want to test which one is the fastest then you can make a test bench.

**Here is an example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
    String a = "ASD";
    String b = "XYZ";
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    int nrOfIterations = 100_000_000;
    int nanoToSec = 1000_000_000;

    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfIterations; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        if (!("".equals(a) && "".equals(b))) {
            long stop = System.nanoTime();
            double result = (stop - start) / (double) nanoToSec;
            sum += result;
        }


        long start2 = System.nanoTime();
        if (!"".equals(a) && !"".equals(b)) {
            long stop2 = System.nanoTime();
            double result2 = (stop2 - start2) / (double) nanoToSec;
            sum2 += result2;
        }
    }

    double average = sum / (double) nrOfIterations;
    String format = df.format(average);
    System.out.println(format + " sec");

    double average2 = sum2 / (double) nrOfIterations;
    String format2 = df.format(average2);
    System.out.println(format2 + " sec");
}
```

**Output:**

```
0,000000047 sec
0,000000048 sec
```

**Comment on output:**

After 100_000_000 iterations the conditions performed pretty much the same.
More iterations will give a more precised average of the performance.